# Display list of time zones similar to that of timezones displayed in S Planner app

Tags: android

Is there a way in which I can display the list of Time zones in a format like (GMT+1.00) Windhoek like the way we see in S Planner on the Android app?

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: You assume that every one know S planner, I would like to help you, but I don't know in whic way S Planner displays timeZone, maybe you can post an image.

Comment: In S Planner click on "+" button on the top to Add event. There you can find TimeZone a picker to select time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest you to create a wrapper class to manage the format of TimeZone objects as follow:

```
 public class TimeZoneWrapper {

    private final TimeZone timeZone;
    private String timeZoneID;
    private String timeZoneDisplay;
    private String timeZoneRawDisplayName;

    public TimeZoneWrapper(final TimeZone timeZone) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
        setDisplayStrings();
    }

    private void setDisplayStrings() {
        this.timeZoneID = timeZone.getID().replaceAll("_", " ");

        int offset = timeZone.getRawOffset();
        if (timeZone.inDaylightTime(new Date())) {
            offset = offset + timeZone.getDSTSavings();
        }

        this.timeZoneRawDisplayName = timeZone.getDisplayName(false,
                TimeZone.SHORT);

        final int offsetHrs = offset / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        final int offsetMins = offset / 1000 / 60 % 60;

        if (offsetHrs + offsetMins == 0) {
            this.timeZoneDisplay = "GMT";
        } else {
            String suffix = "";
            if (offset < 0) {
                suffix += "-";
            } else {
                suffix += "+";
            }
            if (offsetMins != 0) {
                suffix += offsetHrs + "." + offsetMins;
            } else {
                suffix += offsetHrs;
            }

            this.timeZoneDisplay = "GMT" + suffix;
        }
    }

    public String getTimeZoneID() {
        return timeZoneID;
    }

    public String getTimeZoneDisplay() {
        return timeZoneDisplay;
    }

    public String getTimeZoneRawDisplayName() {
        return timeZoneRawDisplayName;
    }

    public TimeZone getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(o instanceof TimeZoneWrapper)) {
            return false;
        }

        final TimeZoneWrapper that = (TimeZoneWrapper) o;
        return that.timeZone.equals(this.timeZone);
    }

}
```

Once you have created (if you want) this wrapper class you can retrieve the TimeZones from your device with the following method in your mainActivity.

```
 private List<TimeZoneWrapper> buildTimeZoneWrappers() {

    final List<TimeZoneWrapper> timeZoneWrappers = new ArrayList<TimeZoneWrapper>();
    final List<TimeZone> timeZones = new ArrayList<TimeZone>();
    final String[] timeZoneIds = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
    for (final String id : timeZoneIds) {
        timeZones.add(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
    }

    for (final TimeZone timeZone : timeZones) {
        timeZoneWrappers.add(new TimeZoneWrapper(timeZone));
    }

    return timeZoneWrappers;
}
```

Now you have a list of "well" formatted timezone, so if you need a picker with this value you simply have to create one with them.

```
String[] temp;
for (int i=0;i<timeZoneWrappers.size();i++){
     temp[i]=timeZoneWrappers.get(i).getTimeZoneDisplay();
}

NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(getApplicationContext());
picker.setDisplayedValues(temp);
```

Let me know;)

Comment: I am able to see a list of TimeZones like GMT, GMT+1,GMT-2 like that .But I need like (GMT +5:30) Kolkata ,(GMT +5:30) Srilanka like that . How can I get the name of location.

Comment: The value GMT + 1 etc correspond to timeZoneWrappers.get(i).getTimeZoneDisplay(), to see the country you have to display timeZoneWrappers.get(i).getTimeZoneID().

Comment: Yes, I did the same way you said.But my requirement is  to display only time zones displayed  "settings" app. So, from Grep code I extracted XML and parsed and compared the one's which we get from the code given by you to the one's present in the xml. My requirement is achieved. Thanks sir